# Initializing new object of operator TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have graph something like this, operators are not important:

```
a = ...
b = ...
c = ...
d = ...
```

And if I call run method like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(100):
        if i != 99:
            aa, bb = sess.run([a, b], feed_dict={ ... })
        else:
            aa, bb, cc = sess.run([a, b, c], feed_dict={ ... })
```

In if block run use same object of operators a and b, but in else branch
creates new objects, and that happens only if I have another node in list in run function. I want to stop that, but I don't know how to do that.